# Symfony2 display associative array in twig

Tags: twig, associative-array

I am new to the Symfony2 framework and am trying to parse some XML from the lastfm API and display information to the user. this would be in the format of album title, playcount and album image for each item.

I can display all this information so far to the user but this is not really useful as I intend to add CSS styling to my page. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is my Controller

```
     /**
 * @Route("/lastfm/albums", name="albums")
 * @Template()
 */
public function albumsAction()
{

$albumsclass = new Album();

   // pull in artist albums
  $albums = simplexml_load_file('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?            method=artist.gettopalbums&artist=imagine+dragons&api_key=370f98844440c2ecc8e5f7        c6cea8a7a4');
$rank = $albums->xpath('/lfm/topalbums/album/@rank');

$album_name_array=array();
$album_playcount_array=array();
$album_url_array=array();
$album_image_array=array();

foreach ($rank as $ranks){

    foreach ($ranks as $rank_id) {

        $album_name = $albums->xpath('/lfm/topalbums/album[@rank="'.$rank_id.'"]/name');
        $album_playcount = $albums->xpath('/lfm/topalbums/album[@rank="'.$rank_id.'"]/playcount');
        $album_url = $albums->xpath('/lfm/topalbums/album[@rank="'.$rank_id.'"]/url');
        $album_image = $albums->xpath('/lfm/topalbums/album[@rank="'.$rank_id.'"]/image[4]');



    }
    $album_name = implode($album_name);  
    array_push($album_name_array,$album_name);

    $album_playcount = implode($album_playcount);
    array_push($album_playcount_array,$album_playcount);

    $album_url = implode($album_url);
    array_push($album_url_array,$album_url);

    $album_image = implode($album_image);
    array_push($album_image_array,$album_image);


}







$container=array();
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($album_name_array); $i++) {
                 array_push($container,$album_name_array[$i],$album_playcount_array[$i],$album_ur     l_array[$i],$album_image_array[$i]);
 }


//$hello = array('album_name'=>$album_name_array,
//           'album_playcount'=>$album_playcount_array,
//            'album_url'=>$album_url_array,
//            'album_image'=>$album_image_array,);
//array_push($album_name_array,$album_playcount_array);


return $this->render('AcmelastfmBundle:Default:albums.html.twig', array(
       // 'pageData' => array(
       //  'artistxml' => $artistxml,

        'rank' => $rank,
        'ranks' => $ranks,
        //'rank_id' => $rank_id,
        // 'ranks' => $ranks,
         'album_name' => $album_name_array,
         //'album_playcount' => $album_playcount_array[$i],
         'album_url' => $album_url_array,
         'album_image' => $album_image_array,
         'container' =>$container,
         'data' => var_export($container, true),
        //  
       //  'hello' => $hello,
        // 'james' => array('album_name' => $albumsclass->getAlbumName()),
     //    ),
        ));



}
```

This is my view

```
 {% extends '::lastfmbase.html.twig' %}
 {% block title %}Albums{% endblock %}

 {% block body %}


{% for key in container %}
{{key}} <br>
{% endfor %}<br>
{% endblock %}
```

I am basically trying to convert this code in PHP to symfony2. However I cannot find a way to pass the associative array values to twig as I get an array to string conversion error

```
<?php
// pull in artist albums
$albums = simplexml_load_file('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?     method=artist.gettopalbums&artist=imagine+dragons&api_key=370f98844440c2ecc8e5f7 c6cea8a7a4');
$rank = $albums->xpath('/lfm/topalbums/album/@rank');

foreach ($rank as $ranks){

    foreach ($ranks as $rank_id) {
        $album_name = $albums->xpath('/lfm/topalbums/album[@rank="'.$rank_id.'"]/name');
        $album_playcount = $albums->xpath('/lfm/topalbums/album[@rank="'.$rank_id.'"]/playcount');
        $album_url = $albums->xpath('/lfm/topalbums/album[@rank="'.$rank_id.'"]/url');
        $album_image = $albums->xpath('/lfm/topalbums/album[@rank="'.$rank_id.'"]/image[4]');
    }



    $album_name = implode($album_name);
    $album_playcount = implode($album_playcount);
    $album_url = implode($album_url);
    $album_image = implode($album_image);

    print_r($rank_id);

    ?>
    <article class="album">
    <?php
    echo "<a href=\"".$album_url."\" target=\"_blank\">".$album_name."</a><br>";
    echo $album_playcount." listeners<br>";
    echo "<div><a href=\"".$album_url."\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"".$album_image."\" title=\"$album_name\" /></a></div><br>";
    ?>
    </article>
    <?php
```

}

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I originally made this site in php http://samuelwong.co.uk/onerepublic/albums and am trying to recreate it in symfony2. I am trying to display the values for album_name, album url in a loop

Comment: Show us what your array looks like in your controller with `print_r` or `var_dump` and show us how the output should be like in twig.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking.
Do you mean this?

```
{% for key, value in container %}
   {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am basically trying to recreate this PHP code in Symfony2.

Comment: this is the output of print_r($container)
Array
(
    [0] => Night Visions
    [1] => 2212749
    [2] => http://www.last.fm/music/Imagine+Dragons/Night+Visions
    [3] => http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/98394887.png
    [4] => Warriors
    [5] => 422558
    [6] => http://www.last.fm/music/Imagine+Dragons/Warriors
    [7] => http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/101137427.png
    [8] => I Bet My Life
    [9] => 196258
    [10] => http://www.last.fm/music/Imagine+Dragons/I+Bet+My+Life
 
)